# Is Digital Certificate private key really private when created by own bank

Tags: security, certificate

If my own bank is the CA not recognized by gov and create my digital certificate, is it theorically possible that they keep a copy somewhere of the private key ? And so what's the value of it in front of a court ?

Answer (score 1):

The normal certificate creation process begins with the owner of the certificate generating the private and public keys, and then getting the public key signed by the certifying authority. In this case, nobody gets to see the private key.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how it is generated.

Normally you, the end user, generates a public/private key pair, then sends a signing request to the CA. The signing request contains the public key and the subject of the certificate. The CA signs it, sends it back, it's paired with your private key and you now have a certificate.

However if the CA just sends you a cert and says here, use this, then they are generating both the public and private key and could indeed have kept a copy.

Comment: Most bank's clients don't know how to generate public/private key so it means Bank will create it for them ?

Comment: The bank could give people instructions, or a web page to do it from which would generate them, then submit the CSR, it's not that hard